# Company's analytics account - How to change admin when current admin is unknown

Tags: google-analytics

We have company's website successfully connected to Google Analytics account, which we can access with one email address. We have only reading rights and can't see the main admin or add other users to the Analytics account. How do we take control of our own analytics without loosing the historical data?

Comment: You will have to create a new GA account, and add new code to the site. You may have to add it to Search Console too. I doubt it. It has been a long time since I have done this. There is no way to recover the GA account that I am aware of. Google is not really helpful on these issues. You will likely have to start over. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to regain access to your admin account, but you would need to do a few things to show that you are the account owners. The steps here will try to help you do that: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/AdWords-Tracking-and-Reporting/How-to-gain-access-to-your-Analytics-account-Property/td-p/436348