# Will creating a new Google analytics ID for my website give me access to historical data

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, accounts, email-accounts

I do not have access to the original gmail account associated with a GA Account ID, so I can't access the existing analytics that have been collected for a website that I am currently maintaining.

I have full access to my website and I was wondering if I put in a new Account ID for GA will I be able to see the historical data or does the data collection start from the time I input the new ID?

Comment: See [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103380/companys-analytics-account-how-to-change-admin-when-current-admin-is-unknown) related question on how to regain access to your Google Analytics account.

Answer (score 1):

A new account, property or view will not have any historical data. It starts fresh and clean. The only way to keep historical data is to maintain the original account.

Nevertheless, you can export your analytics data into another platform and that way you can have previous and recent data altogether.

You can also contact Google in order to try to recover access to the old account. You should prove you are the company in charge of this account. Sometimes they go through it but it's not easy.